# Differential equation change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $$xy''(x) +(n+1-x)y'(x) + ay(x)=0.$$
If I set $x=r^t$ then how to plug in this and how to use change of variable to get the differential equation for $r$ instead of $x,$ i.e. the following equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{dr}{dx}$$

Comment: You sure that last term is $ay'(x)$ and not just $ay(x)$?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, it should be y(x)

Comment: Anyway, you have a good start. As for the sub I'd recommend to find $y_x$ through $y_r = y_x x_r$, not if that matters, just might cause less confusion.

Answer (score 13):

By chain rule
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{dr}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dr^2}\bigg(\frac{dr}{dx}\bigg)^2+\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{d^2r}{dx^2}$$
where
$$x=r^t\Rightarrow dx=tr^{t-1}dr\Rightarrow\frac{dr}{dx}=\frac 1{tr^{t-1}}$$
$$dx^2=t(t-1)r^{t-2}dr^2\Rightarrow\frac{d^2r}{dx^2}=\frac 1{t(t-1)r^{t-2}}$$
By plugging into original equation
$$r^t \Bigg(\frac{d^2y}{dr^2}\bigg(\frac 1{tr^{t-1}}\bigg)^2+\frac{dy}{dr}\frac 1{t(t-1)r^{t-2}} \Bigg)+(n+1-r^t)\frac{dy}{dr}\frac 1{tr^{t-1}} + ay=0$$

---- Addition for chain rule ----
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{dr}{dx}\bigg)$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dr}\bigg)\frac{dr}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{dr}{dx}\bigg)$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dr^2}\frac{dr}{dx}\frac{dr}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{d^2r}{dx^2}$$

Comment: how does $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac{d^2y}{dr^2}\bigg(\frac{dr}{dx}\bigg)^2+\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{d^2r}{dx^2}$ follow from the chain rule?

Comment: @fawningflagellum Please check the added section

Comment: @MichaelAngelo By applying $\frac{d}{dx}=(\frac{dr}{dx})\frac{d}{dr}$ to both sides of the chain rule equation above, and using the product rule on the right hand side.